Как сделать текст по кругу
Мне нужно сделать текст по кругу, как на фото: 
Нужно, чтобы можно было поставить определёный размер всего блока, текст расширялся автоматически по кругу.

Что Вы уже сделали, и что конкретно не получилось? Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив код своих попыток.

ну очень популярный вопрос. вы грамматическую ошибку специально вставили в заголовок, чтобы движок вам не писал, что вопрос с таким заголовком уже существует?

Попробуй этот вариант


svg {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <!-- Круг -->
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="150" fill="#e9e9e9" />

    <!-- Текст внутри круга -->
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-family="Arial" font-size="24" fill="black">Текст внутри круга</text>

    <!-- Кривая для текста по окружности -->
    <path id="textPath" d="M 250 250 m -150, 0 a 150,150 0 1,1 300,0 a 150,150 0 1,1 -300,0" fill="none" />

    <!-- Текст, который обвит -->
    <text font-family="Arial" font-size="18" fill="black">
      <textPath xlink:href="#textPath">
      Здесь может быть ваш текст, который обвит вокруг круга.
      Здесь может быть ваш текст, который обвит вокруг круга.
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>




Попробуй этот вариант

А как зделать размер 190 на 190 пикселей?

Добро пожаловать на сайт, h0nova ! Ознакомьтесь как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (если ваш вопрос получит много минусов, то вы получите блокировку, и не сможете задавать новые вопросы) также, если данный ответ вас устроил, нажмите на галочку под ответом, чтоб принять данный ответ.

Ну что бы каждое слово не разбивать на span мы используем javascript
После этого в css повернём каждый span на 8.3deg
В итоге код будет такой:


let text = document.querySelector(".item p")

text.innerHTML = text.innerText.split("").map((char, i) =>
  `<span style="transform:rotate(${i * 8.3}deg)">${char}</span>`
).join("")
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: consolas;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.item span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  transform-origin: 0px 130px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
<div class="circle">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Лично отбираю участников отбираю участников</p>
  </div>
</div>




Тренировался здесь: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ExJpbZa
